# Radius Centre Form Of Circle

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

I am having a small problem in the basics of the radius centre form of the circle.
Suppose you are given that : "A curve is given as x²+y²=a²"
It is not explicitly mentioned that a is radius(although in this given equation, it has to be the radius).
So my doubt is whether you will take the value of a only greater than 0 (as it is the radius), or can it be any number (the radius will be |a|)?
Like do you take the number 'a' as the radius of the given circle or '|a|'?

Comment: Radius is a distance, so it is positive. You need to take the $a$ positive. Or, in equations like $x^2+y^2 = p$, you take the _positive square-root_ of $p$ as the radius.

Comment: But if it is not given a is the radius, then do you take radius as |a| or do you just take a as the radius?

Comment: You will be given equations like $x^2+y^2 = 25$, so the radius is $5$ and not in any case $-5$. You may be given $x^2+y^2 = 5^2$, where $a=5$, so you take $a$ as the radius. I doubt you will be given something like $x^2+y^2 = (-5)^2$, where the radius, again, will be $5 = |a| = \sqrt{a^2}$.

Comment: So actually the question (in physics) was that a reflecting surface has the equation x² + y² = a² then the answer would vary depending on whether a is postive or negative, so what would you do here?

Comment: you _can't_ have a _negative radius_, so you'll have to take the positive $a$.

Comment: Oh ok, understood, thank you!