# Doubt in the signs of variables in the general equation of the circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

So my question goes like this
"For the circles $C_1$: $x^2+y^2-10x+16y+89-r^2=0$ and $C_2$ $x^2+y^2+6x-14y+42=0$, the number of integral values of $r$ for which the circles are intersecting are?"

I do not have a doubt in the solving itself, but the problem is that in a general equation of a circle $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$, $r$ is always positive, but here in circle $C_1$ (simplifying, we get $(x-5)^2+(y+8)^2=r^2$), they have taken the value of radius as $|r|$ and found the number of integral values of $r$ ($13<|r|<21$, so $14$ values for $r$). Is this the correct way? If yes, then when do we take radius simply $r$, and when do we take it as $|r|$?

Comment: In what you call "general equation of the circle", the radius is $|r|$. If you happen to know that $r\geq0$, then the radius is $r=|r|$. Knowing that $r\geq0$ is extra information, which in your problem is not given, or assumed.

Comment: Well in both these questions, I got the answer that r has to be positive and so you don't have to take |r|

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/744130/doubt-regarding-the-mathematics-in-reflecting-surfaces/

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612762/radius-centre-form-of-circle

Comment: Yes, the claims made there are improperly explained or wrong, if you read them strictly as written. What they meant to say is that if $r$ is supposed to be representing the length of the radius, then $r$ is non-negative. But $r$ can be negative. In that case it is not the length of the radius. The length of the radius would be $|r|$.

Comment: It is as simple as this: The equations $x^2+y^2=(-1)^2$ and $x^2+y^2=1^2$ are equivalent. Both set of solutions are the unit circle. The length of the radius is $|-1|=1$.

Comment: But everywhere I saw the general centre radius form of the circle, in the r² term, r is taken to be positive, then why not here? Because even though (-1)² and (1)² are equivalent for x² + y² = (±1)², but for a circle equation, you cannot write x² + y² = (-a)² (a is positive), you have to write (a² only)

Comment: Because the term inside the square determines the radius, not it's magnitude, the number itself is the radius.

Comment: Look at the sentence that you are saying: "centre radius". Yes, if you are already assuming that $r$ is radius, you are implicitly assuming that you will write it non-negative. Nobody stops you from writing the equation $x^2+y^2=(-1)^2$. This equation exists and its set of solutions over the real numbers has a geometric interpretation. It would be, the circle with centre $(0,0)$ and radius (???) Exactly. Radius $|-1|$.

Comment: I understood your point, but general convention states that in a circle equation you cannot put it as (-a)², so if you talk only about circles equations and not look at the geometric meaning of x²+y² = (-1)², then you will have to take the term inside the square positive only.

Comment: Sure. But now read the problem that you were solving? Did they mention anywhere that $r$ is supposed to mean length of a radius? If they didn't, then it is not warranted to assume it.

Comment: That's what my question was, they didn't mean it was the length of the radius, but simplifying, we get it as (x-h)²+(y-k)²=r² then r has to be positive according to the aforementioned convention, because they did give it was the equation of a circle, and in a circle, in the r² term, r has to be taken positive.

Comment: I don't see anywhere, at least in your quote of the problem, that $r$ is supposed to mean radius. Do you?

Comment: Anyway, there is no new information in this discussion. That's it. If the problem mentioned that $r$ is radius or that $r$ is non-negative, then you can assume it, if the problem didn't then you cannot assume it. There is nothing more.

Comment: That was what i was asking actually, they did not mean it was the radius, but after simplifying, it came out to be the radius, so do we still treat it as a variable, or do we use the conventions of the circle's radius centre form and take r as only postive?

Comment: Reading the problem as stated, the value $r = -15$ is just as good as the value $r = 15$ because both result in circles that intersect at a tangent point, and $r$ is stated merely as a name of a variable, not the name of a "radius". However, I disagree with the given solution: a point of tangency is a point of intersection, albeit a special kind, and therefore I count $18$ values of $r$ that result in intersecting circles.

Comment: Ok i got it, thank you so much.

Comment: The task is not well formulated. Obviously they want the solution count understood for the algebraic problem. Thus negative values for $r$ are admissible. But then they formulate the constraint geometrically "circles intersecting", and geometric circles have a positive radius. To make this consistent from the algebraic point-of-view, $C_1,C_2$ have to be declared real algebraic varieties, or that only real intersection points are of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

That's correct. Radii of circles drawn are $(13,4).$ Extreme radii at $(A,B)$ are $(13,13+8=21)$ excluded in a count as making tangential contact (black).

The intersecting (like blue) circles have radii $(14,15,16,17,18,19,20),$ seven non-tangential integer radii in all.

Comment: But then what will be the number of values of r? 7 or 14?

Comment: Tangent lines intersect the circles they are tangent to. This is often used (although sometimes not very well) as a definition of a tangent to ta circle.

Comment: @Ham Lemon: (14,20,1) seven in all, excluding tangential circles, nine if tangential circles are included.

Comment: @ David K: Yes, coincident /double intersection or root for tangents.

Comment: So we don't consider the negative values of r like -14 and -15 and all?

Comment: Polar and cartesian forms of a circle x2+y2=r2=a2 admit r=±a$ so by convention we take the positive root.

Comment: Oh, i did not know this, thank you